# Keras Import Error: No module named 'google', Jupyter Notebook Anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

I am using the remote GPU and writing the code in jupyter notebook. While Importing keras i am facing the error of "no module named 'google'. I searched a lot but all in vain. Below is the list of import libraries:

I have updated anaconda environment conda update conda but problem persist. i am using UBUNTU LTS 16.04 on remote GPU server while UBUNTU LTS 18.04 on local machine.

```
import numpy as np
import keras

from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Model
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Activation
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Flatten
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.optimizers import Nadam
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau, ModelCheckpoint
from keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.convolutional import *

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, roc_curve, auc
from scipy import interp

from itertools import cycle
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

Following is the error

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-aeb0232d91c1> in <module>
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 import keras
      3 
      4 from keras import backend as K
      5 from keras.models import Model

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/__init__.py in <module>
      1 from __future__ import absolute_import
      2 
----> 3 from . import utils
      4 from . import activations
      5 from . import applications

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py in <module>
      4 from . import data_utils
      5 from . import io_utils
----> 6 from . import conv_utils
      7 
      8 # Globally-importable utils.

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/utils/conv_utils.py in <module>
      7 from six.moves import range
      8 import numpy as np
----> 9 from .. import backend as K
     10 
     11 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/backend/__init__.py in <module>
     87 elif _BACKEND == 'tensorflow':
     88     sys.stderr.write('Using TensorFlow backend.\n')
---> 89     from .tensorflow_backend import *
     90 else:
     91     # Try and load external backend.

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in <module>
      3 from __future__ import print_function
      4 
----> 5 import tensorflow as tf
      6 from tensorflow.python.framework import ops as tf_ops
      7 from tensorflow.python.training import moving_averages

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py in <module>
     22 
     23 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
---> 24 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
     25 
     26 try:

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py in <module>
     57 
     58 # Protocol buffers
---> 59 from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
     60 from tensorflow.core.framework.node_def_pb2 import *
     61 from tensorflow.core.framework.summary_pb2 import *

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/graph_pb2.py in <module>
      4 import sys
      5 _b=sys.version_info[0]<3 and (lambda x:x) or (lambda x:x.encode('latin1'))
----> 6 from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
      7 from google.protobuf import message as _message
      8 from google.protobuf import reflection as _reflection

ImportError: No module named 'google'
```

Looking for solution, if somebody can help me out in this Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're getting this error. I ran your code. It's working fine for me. Just comment "%matplotlib inline" if you want to run this as a python script not in Jupyter.

Comment: thanks for contributing, i also tried this it also didnt worked. I am using the following versions of python and other libraries :                                      Python= 3.6.6, Keras=2.2.4, tensorflow=1.9.0, i am amazed why this problem is still persist. Need some more solution.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS - Installing tensorflow 1.3 - it will automatically remove other protobuf installs and install protobuf 3.4. However, this does not work and neither does installing or downgrading to any other protobuf version.

However I found a solution.
Not sure why this works - but on Mac OS this solved it.

```
pip install google
```

In windows check whether it is installed.

```
$ pip list | grep -i keras
Keras (1.1.0)
```

It’s a bad idea to use and pollute your system-wide Python. I recommend using a virtualenv (see this guide).

The best usage is to create a `virtualenv` directory (in your home, for instance), and store your virtualenvs in:

```
cd virtualenv/
virtualenv -p python3.5 py-keras
source py-keras/bin/activate
pip install -q -U pip setuptools wheel
```

Then install Keras:

```
pip install keras
```

You get:

```
$ pip list
Keras (1.1.0)
numpy (1.11.2)
pip (8.1.2)
PyYAML (3.12)
scipy (0.18.1)
setuptools (28.3.0)
six (1.10.0)
Theano (0.8.2)
wheel (0.30.0a0)
```

But, you also need to install extra libraries, like Tensorflow:

```
$ python -c "import keras"
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Follow this link to install necessary packages..https://www.tensorflow.org/install

Comment: thanks for your comment, i am already working in virtual environment. I am using the following versions of python and other libraries :                                      Python= 3.6.6, Keras=2.2.4, tensorflow=1.9.0, i am amazed why this problem is still persist. Please need some extra solution.